# Can't Dockerize my simple typescript website

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express

I am trying to get a Typescript project running in Docker. I created the Docker file based on a tutorial but when I run it I get:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 8: exec: .: Permission denied

I am not sure how to diagnosis this problem.

I can enter the container with

```
docker run --rm -it d3ca97c88aec bash -il
```

and run the server with

```
npm start
```

I have no file called docker-entrypoint.sh and I didn't make one.

I STRONGLY FEEL THIS IS BECAUSE TYPESCRIPT MAKES A BUILD FOLDER AND THAT BUILD FOLDER IS PERMISSIONED DIFFERENTLY.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
ENV COUCH_URL=NotSafeForStackOverflow

RUN npx tsc

EXPOSE 8080
CMD npx ts-node index.ts
```

---

```
{
  "name": "express-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "private": null,
  "dependencies": {
    "agentkeepalive": "^4.1.3",
    "apollo-utilities": "^1.3.4",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.11.0",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "merge-graphql-schemas": "^1.7.8",
    "nano": "^8.2.2",
    "node-webcrypto-ossl": "^2.1.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx ts-node index.ts",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch '**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you launching the container normally?

Comment: docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 containerName .

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` is an `ENTRYPOINT` script defined by the `node` image. Have you read through `https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image`? You say that manually running `npm start` works, but in your dockerfile you're running `npx ts-node index.ts
`. Why the difference?

Comment: "npm start" calls "npx ts-node index.ts". Running npx ts-node index.ts will all run the project. There is nothing about this error in https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image

Answer (score -1):

when you run `CMD npx ts-node index.ts`
it will overwrite default `CMD [ "node" ]`

please refer link below to how to use node image :

```
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image
```

you shoud be able done by using docker-compose :

```
version: "2"
services:
  node:
    image: "node:8"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    expose:
      - "8081"
    command: "npm start"
```